# How to customize the "You are not allowed to respond again to this survey" SharePoint page?

Tags: branding, survey-list

When a user tries to respond more than once to a survey that does not allow more than one response, the user gets a SharePoint error page saying "You are not allowed to respond again to this survey".

Is there a way to customize this page to have the same look and feel of the site rather than the default SharePoint error page.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2007, but in 2010, if you have _publishing_ enabled, you can apply a custom master page to all sites and subsites - it styles ALL of the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has the same answer as the access denied page on this question:  [How to customize the "access denied" SharePoint Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/how-to-customize-the-access-denied-sharepoint-page)

Comment: Be aware that simple.master (along with other master pages such as application.master) "belongs" to Microsoft and should not be edited. These files can be overwritten without warning when upgrading SharePoint. Instead you should consider using the HttpModule approach. Read the two excellent articles on this subject http://blogs.msdn.com/chandru/archive/2009/12/11/customize-sign-in-as-different-user-for-an-expired-active-directory-password.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/bgeoffro/archive/2007/11/12/branding-a-moss-corporate-intranet-portal-part-1a-high-level-overview-terminology-and-approach.aspx

Answer (score -1):

change CallStack value to true in web.config

```
<SharePoint>
    <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="false" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="true">
```

Comment: That's not an answer to OPs' question.

Comment: In this way you will help prevent the opening of the error screen