# Can I alter the display message on the Access Request/Denied page?

Tags: access, access-denied

I have inherited a SharePoint site that contains data used by specific employee groups across 2,000+ locations. We have automated access to these people, but if they try to access the site via link instead of through our intranet portal, SharePoint detects them as "Location PC" and denies them access and asks them to request access from me. They then send me an email saying "I am the supervisor at location X. Please give access." without providing a name, and I have no way of responding to them to tell them to use the intranet for access, not a link.

Ultimately, my question is, can I alter the message on the Access Request/Denied page to say "When making a request for access, please include your full name."?

Regrettably, I have no experience in HTML and am stuck using default SharePoint capabilities, so I do not believe this is a duplicate of [How to customize the "access denied" SharePoint Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/how-to-customize-the-access-denied-sharepoint-page).

Comment: When you receive an access request to a page you should see the user name.  Are you just referring to the page they see whenever they are denied access?

Comment: @FlatBanana their user name is a generic "Location PC" because they are not logging in in a way that SharePoint picks up their actual ID, so I do not even get an identifier beyond what they tell me in their request email, which is usually just a location number.